# Cannot render plot inside dynamic UI, when using a shiny module

Tags: r, module, shiny

Normally, Shiny has no problem generating plots from within UIs that the user calls reactively, but I've noticed that when using a shiny module to dynamically generate the UI, the plot does not appear.

Below is a minimal example of a modularized shiny app that reproduces the problem; it is supposed to generate a ui with a plot in it when the user presses the "go" button:

```
library("shiny")

exampleUI <- function(id, label = "example") {
        ns <- NS(id)
        tagList(   actionButton(ns("go"), "Go"),   uiOutput(ns("ui"))   )
}


ui <- fluidPage(   exampleUI("example")   )

example <- function(input, output, session) {
        observeEvent(input$go, {
                output$plot <- renderPlot(   plot(1:5, 1:5)   )
                output$ui <- renderUI(   plotOutput("plot")   )
        })
}

server <- function(input, output) {    callModule(example, "example")    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

By contrast, the non-modularized version works as expected:

```
ui <- fluidPage(   
        tagList(   actionButton("go", "Go"),   uiOutput("ui")   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {     

        observeEvent(input$go, {
                output$plot <- renderPlot(   plot(1:5, 1:5)   )
                output$ui <- renderUI(   plotOutput("plot")   )
        })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would appreciate any pointers on how to make the first code block behave like the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

exampleUI <- function(id, label = "example") {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(   actionButton(ns("go"), "Go"),   uiOutput(ns("ui"))   )
}


example <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$go, {
        output$plot <- renderPlot(   plot(1:5, 1:5)   )
        ns <- session$ns
        output$ui <- renderUI(   plotOutput(ns("plot"))   )
    })
}


ui <- fluidPage(   exampleUI("example")   )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(example, "example") 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Two things:

1. You referred to `exampleUI` before defining it (In your actual example, you will probably `source` the module, so this shouldn't be a problem)
2. When using `renderUI` in modules which contain input/output you need to wrap it within `ns`. Read the section on [Using renderUI within modules](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) for more

Comment: I edited my question to fix (1), which was an oversight (hidden by the fact I'd stored exampleUI several times before), in case people who see this question later want to run the code. Calling ns inside the server module was new to me, though.